# Trying to create a lock system

Tags: windows, batch

I've been trying to create a locking system just to help deepen my understanding of batch files. To clear things up, this isn't supposed to be very complex or even practical. This is just more of something I've been wanting to learn how to create. Sure, if I needed an actual extra password system, I could find a program online. If you are only here to say that I could just find one online, believe me, I know. As stated before, I simply wish to learn how to make this work.

In theory, it's supposed to run on startup and then ask for a password to continue. If no password is entered within 10 seconds, then the system restarts itself. If the password is incorrect or the window is closed the system should restart itself. I've just started working with batch last night, and it being my first ever in-depth experience with coding has viciously confused me.

I was going to have it open another batch file that constantly asks the other window if it is open, and vice versa, but I was unable to find a way to send commands between batch programs. The biggest problem I've been having is I cannot get the countdown (from 10) to allow input. This is what I have so far, sorry for being so terrible at this (I removed the restart command for testing reasons):

```
    @echo off
    color 02 
    title DPS
    echo Input the correct password before you continue, please. 
    set/p input=
    if %input%==prot goto end
    goto wrong
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
    cls
    echo 10 -Input the correct password before you continue, please.
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
    cls
    echo 9 - Input the correct password before you continue, please.
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
    cls
    echo 8 - Input the correct password before you continue, please.
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
    cls
    echo 7 - Input the correct password before you continue, please.
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
    cls
    echo 6 - Input the correct password before you continue, please.
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
    cls
    echo 5 - Input the correct password before you continue, please.
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
    cls
    echo 4 - Input the correct password before you continue, please.
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
    cls
    echo 3 - Input the correct password before you continue, please.
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
    cls
    echo 2 - Input the correct password before you continue, please.
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
    cls
    echo 1 - Input the correct password before you continue, please.
    ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
    cls
    echo 0
    echo (restart script here)
    :end
    echo Welcome back.
    pause
    exit
    :wrong 
    echo (restart script here)
    pause
```

Comment: Why create an artificial security and just use he os security?

Comment: There are programs that do this for you - look around. It's much easier than making one yourself. BTW, someone could just login using safe mode or similar and uninstall the security altogether if they knew your system password.

Comment: You do realize that if someone do have your username and password to login, they can open task manager and kill that batch script right? (all within 10 seconds)

Comment: You understand that unless your device's local disk is encypted this could be disabled like child's play?

Comment: Please re-read the first paragraph.

Comment: @user3362503 - Your entire question is a single paragraph.  Its really simple your idea isn't secure and does provide ANY SECURITY AT ALL.

Comment: You'd have (some) better luck using VBScript instead of a limited use batch file.

Comment: Thanks for an actual reply. I'm not sure what VBS is, if you could give a quick bit of info on it and where to acquire the software, that'd be greatly appreciated.